# Duplicate Azure Table

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

**TL;DR;**
Is there a way to duplicate a azure table in a automated, cost-effective way?
**Long Version**
I have a multi-tenant cloud-service with quite a few tables. Now i'm making a move to use the "staging" deploy of the cloud service so I can make the "RC" version of my system available to client... This new versions might be a bug correction version or maybe a "new module" version...
Today the beta versions use a pre-defined test load the comprehends "all" scenarios and it's fine, but not ideal.
What i would like to do is to have the user testing new versions using their own replicated data. The user would go to the management portal, click the "**Refresh** test set" and go testing. New costumers evaluating the product would use the old test set...

My problem is: Replicate a table by "insert into mytableCopy select * from myTable" is expensive!

- It's expensive in time. i'm taking about 20 min to duplicate all tables using a dedicated medium worker role. Since the users are eargerly asking for this feature and they love real-time data i'm projecting that the will "spam-click" the Refresh Test Set button. Taking 20 min to replicate it would be a major problem... yes i have to duplicate all data because alot of the reports deal with trends.
- It's expensive in cost. running the extra-instance is a fixed cost. the extra storage is a reasonable but projectable cost (it's not cheap but i can predict it). the cost i'm worried about is the **storage transaction** cost that can stack-up real fast! If addoption is 1/3 of the expected, my transactions bill will go up 500% with each new "bug-fixed" version and 10000% with each "new module" version... the storage price i can mitigate by simply deleting the duplicated data off-business hours and the extra-instance i can shut down...

So basically my question is how do i get out of the pickle?!?

1. Is there a way to "avoid" the transactions cost or diminish it?!?
2. Is there a more fast way to duplicate the table?

(the calc for usage is based on how many times the users already click my "**Reset** test set" button today)

Comment: Is there a reason you have to import all data? Can't you just import the data that has changed? If you have a CreatedDate field, use that to only import new data, similar concept for ModifiedDate. If you don't have those fields, that might be worth adding.

Comment: now a days in order to save on storage we delete the table if it's not used for more than a day, which we interpret as "we the interested costumers already tested the bug-fix/new-module"... I think that it's something to keep doing because it's a 13-20 days of avoided-billing each month...

Comment: @nate that got me thinking: probably now (with real data) the users will take longer to validate... i will strongly consider ur sugestion!

Answer (score 2):

The main delay of your task is the Context roadmap. When you request your data the context create proxies for all your entities and maybe keep track of those. To avoid this delay you can use the REST API directly instead of the .Net Client Library

In the past I develop an Azure Storage Proxy service that act as a middleware between my clients apps and my real storage.

Check [Rest API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179423.aspx)

The solution road map could be something like that:

1-) READ TABLES

2-) CREATE CLONE TABLES

3-) FOR EACH TABLE READ PAGE BY PAGE

4-) Transform using regular expressions the RESPONSE from the original and use as the Body of the INSERT operation into the clone

Hope this help!!!